# Symfony syntax error, unexpected '?' from a file in vendor

Tags: symfony, syntax-error

I know this has been asked a lot but I can't find out the error even with the other posts.
So, I have this error:

```
syntax error, unexpected '?', expecting function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST)
```

It leads to this line in Proxy Manager vendor, Configuration.php:

```
protected ?string $proxiesTargetDir;
```

The thing is, since it is in a vendor, I don't know how to resolve that, and I don't even know where is the syntax error, everything seems fine.
Any ideas?

Comment: That's php 7.4 syntax, you can enforce the php [configuring composer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#platform) and reinstalling packages.

Comment: You are using a package that requires PHP 7.4, and you are using a version < 7.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was because of my php version and a dependancy.